# Getting a WPF ListView to fill enitre column

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I am fairly new to WPF. I am going about a window where as on the column on the left, the data input is shown on a `ListView`, and data input is shown on the column to its right.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="98*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="195*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">

            <Button Name="SaveButton" Content="Save Revision File" />
            <Button Name="DeleteSelected" Content="Delete Selected" Click="DeleteSelected_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="ToAppendListView" SelectionChanged="ToAppendListView_Selected" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Look Cover Type: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LookCoverTypeContent.Content}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="Quiz Question: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuizContent.Content}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text=", " />
                            <TextBlock Text="Flashcard Front: " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlashCardContent.Content}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
        <!-- Data Input -->
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My problem is that I cannot get the `ListView` to fill the left hand column, so it will dynamically expand downwards and off the windows, and one the screen is filled, it will not be able to scroll, so content is appearing off the window.

I have tried to use the vertical alignment stretch, but alas this did not work.Is there a way to ensure that the position of the `ListView` is fixed, and to enable scrolling once the screen is filled?

Comment: Too many StackPanels

Comment: When in doubt, use some ugly background colors to see what is where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Column=0 StackPanel:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="98*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="195*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">

    </Grid>            
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
       <!-- Data Input -->
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` on the ListView can go.

I have my doubts about the StackPanel in Column=1  (not =2) as well.
And about the inner one with the buttons.

Comment: Any suggestions of what should be used instead of stack panels?

Comment: In this case: just nothing. For the other cases: not enough information.